# Airflow: How to make sure that DAG run after every 5 minutes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am exploring `Apache Airflow`. I am using a method that inserts a record in MySQL.

I have scheduled the `DAG` to run after EVERY 5 minutes but it does not seem happening as MYSQL timestamp tells that the MySQL task is being executed many times within 5 minutes.

[image]

As you can see it is inserting record within minutes. Below is my code:

```
import datetime as dt

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def fetch_data_mysql():
    mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='mysql_default')
    sql = 'SELECT * from random_table'
    sql = "INSERT INTO random_table(text) VALUES ('Hi Adnan')"
    print('INSERT MYSQL RESULT')
    # results = mysql_hook.get_records(sql)
    # results = mysql_hook.run(sql, autocommit=True, parameters=('Hi Addu',))
    mysql_hook.run(sql, autocommit=True)

def print_world():
    print('world')
    return 'WORLD IN SEPTEMBER'


default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2018, 9, 11),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=2),
}

with DAG('airflow_tutorial_v01',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='0/5 * * * *',
         ) as dag:
    print_hello = BashOperator(task_id='print_hello',
                               bash_command='echo "hello"')
    sleep = BashOperator(task_id='sleep',
                         bash_command='sleep 5')
    print_world = PythonOperator(task_id='print_world',
                                 python_callable=print_world)
    mysql_task = PythonOperator(task_id='mysql_tut', python_callable=fetch_data_mysql)

print_hello >> sleep >> print_world >> mysql_task
```

I am using `v1.10.0`.

The link of the log is given here:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0g64mhi8sgzlvw/my_simple_dag.py.log?dl=0

Comment: At first I thought it was a catchup issue, but I assume you are in a timezone where those timestamps were pretty close to the current time.  Is your database set up so that on insert your updated_at time gets set as well?

Comment: @cwurtz Yes I am checking locally my timezone is UTC+5 but Airflow I guess is UTC.

Comment: @cwurtz can you elaborate more?

Comment: Is it possible that a bunch of DagRuns got clogged up in your queue and your workers processed them rather quickly in series when they eventually got picked up?

Comment: @Chris I am a newbie so not sure. However, everytime MySQL routine was queued. Rest executed instantly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dag is backfilling. If you check the logs its execution dates are `2018-09-20 00:15:00+00:00`, `2018-09-20 00:20:00+00:00`, `2018-09-20 00:25:00+00:00`, and so on.

Add the following to your `default_args`:

`'catchup_by_default': False`

Your `default_args` should look like:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2018, 9, 11),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=2),
    'catchup_by_default': False,
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So it backfills w.r.t to the different between `start_date` and `excution_time`? Does it mean that if `start_date` is `datetime(2018, 9, 11,00:00:00)` and I execute at `00:00:30` with time interval of *5 mins*, it will first backfill *6 DAG Runs* and then will continue in future?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your cron schedule from `0/5 * * * *` to `*/5 * * * *`. The latter is every five minutes, whereas the former seems to be a non-standard cron syntax according to [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0/5_*_*_*_*)

Comment: That was typo while writing here. In reality it is `*/5`. The only delay I see is due to `sleep` otherwise no delay of 5 mins. The link of log is given here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0g64mhi8sgzlvw/my_simple_dag.py.log?dl=0

Comment: Why multiple instances of Dag Runs are being run?